# Yii2 disable asset of a vendor module

Tags: module, yii2, assets, vendor, assetbundle

I have installed yii2-admin module, located in /vendor/mdmsoft/yii2-admin but I don't want it to load its own asset bundle. It there any way to disable this module asset bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and even mentioned in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles). One way to do it is through application config:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'mdm\admin\AdminAsset' => false,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Another way - during runtime through component:

```
\Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['mdm\admin\AdminAsset'] = false;
```

Comment: No I want to dissable asset bundle of that module only. I dont want to disable 'yii\web\JqueryAsset' bundle.

Comment: Obviously I just mentioned this as an example. Replace with asset bundle you want to disable, you didn't provide any information about its namespace.

Comment: My bad, its namespace is 'mdm\admin' provided in file AdminAsset.php.

Comment: Updated answer with this bundle.