# disable multiple jquery versions loading

Tags: jquery, yii2

I'm using Yii 2.0.9 and it's loading jquery 2.2.4, which I have no problem with. The problem is I've installed the krajee extensions and it's loading jquery 1.7.2, which I don't really want. How can I adjust my AppAssets so that it will fall back to the jquery version that is already being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think that jQuery of different version (1.7.2) is loaded from somewhere else, because Kartik's widgets has separate "base" repository and defines its own [AssetBundle](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base/blob/master/AssetBundle.php) which acts as base for widgets and has dependencies only on Yii's core asset bundles:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
];
```

Anyway, I see few possible options here.

First, recognize where another version of jQuery is loaded from.

**1)** If it's in your own code - just remove this dependency.

If it's in vendor module:

**2)** If jQuery is defined in separate `AssetBundle`, you can disable this asset bundle with jQuery like described in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30472905/4323648).

**3)** If it's defined as simple reference to file, you can remove it like so:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'used\extension\AssetBundle' => [
                    'js' => [
                        'path/to/jquery1.7.2.js', // Remove jQuery 1.7.2 from here (do not include this)
                        // Extension's other assets
                        'path/to/extension.js',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Or you can do the same during runtime as decribed in option **2)**

**4)** You can disable extension's `AssetBundle` completely using option **2)**, define your own, customize it as you want (you can subclass existing) and register in desired place.

Read more about assets in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).