# How to disable Yii2 pjax asset loading automatically

Tags: jquery, yii2, pjax

How can I stop Yii2 from loading the pjax asset file automatically when I use the Pjax widget?  I want to load it myself from a CDN.  I've tried this:

```
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\PjaxAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

But that doesn't do anything.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\PjaxAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null,
            'js'=> ['//cdn.url.you/want/to/use']
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. I've also disabled Jquery and Bootstrap and those all disappear but the Pjax file is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you could choose to disable specific asset bundle.

If you want to disable specific asset, use this:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\PjaxAsset' => false,
   ],
]
```

If you want to disable whole asset bundles, use this:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => false,
]
```

---

- Similar question here: [Yii2 disable asset of a vendor module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472821/yii2-disable-asset-of-a-vendor-module/49982228#49982228)
- Additional official document about this: "[Yii2 Guide: Structure Assets - Customizing Asset Bundles](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#customizing-asset-bundles)".